# finding index of max value in an array in C

Tags: c

I want to find index of max value in array in C.

I write this code example:

```
maks=0;
for(i=0;i< N * N;i++) {
    if(array[i]>maks) {
        maks=(int) array[i];
        k=i;
    }
}
```

But this isn't work properly.Could you advise me another example please?

Best Regards...

Comment: Have you initialized `k` with zero, too?

Comment: What is N equal to? Where is the declaration for `max`? What is `k`?

Comment: as long as `k`, `array` and `N` are correctly initialized, your code should work. Can you be more precise about the problem ?

Comment: Accept some answers first. Also, stop answering your own questions without actually answering them. You should read the FAQ.

Comment: Not exactly a Correct question. Here is an example for your help. int maxMarks = Int32.MinValue; int arrayLength = array.Length; for(int index = 0; index < arrayLength; index++){ if((int)array[index]>maxMarks){ maxMarks = (int)array[index]}} Console.WriteLine("MaxMarks{0}",maxMarks);

Comment: Why boundary is equal to `N*N`?

Comment: Why the cast: `(int) array[i]` ? What's actually in your `array` ? If it's not an int, what do you expect the cast to do ? If it's an int, there's no need for the cast.

Answer (score 8):

```
k = 0;
max = array[k];

for (i = 0; i < N * N; ++i)
{
    if (array[i] > max)
    {
        max = (int)array[i];
        k = i;
    }
}
```

Should work !

Comment: @red1ynx zero-sized objects are illegal in C. GNU C allows such arrays, but it's not standard.

Comment: you can make it i = 1 to star the loop

Comment: @user703016, I am sorry i was wrong, according to code snippet in the question it should be N*N not N*2

Answer (score 1):

Below function accepts pointer to array with size of the array as arguments and returns the max index.

```
  int max_index(float *a, int n)
    {
        if(n <= 0) return -1;
        int i, max_i = 0;
        float max = a[0];
        for(i = 1; i < n; ++i){
            if(a[i] > max){
                max = a[i];
                max_i = i;
            }
        }
        return max_i;
    }
```

Usage example,

```
float a[3] ={1.2,3.2,4.0};
cout<<max_index(a,3)<<endl; //will output 2, because a[2] element is the max
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.