# How to find the position of maximum in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of 16 integer values where  each value is 32 bits each as shown. I can find the maximum of the array as follows.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <conio.h>
   // main program 
int main(void){
    int i, max;
  int  array[16]; 
  array[0]=0x1;
  array[1]=0x6;
  array[2]=0x8;
  array[3]=0xC;
  array[4]=0x7;
  array[5]=0x9;
  array[6]=0xB;
  array[7]=0x0;
  array[8]=0x3;
  array[9]=0x6;
  array[10]=0x7;
  array[11]=0x6;
  array[12]=0x15;
  array[13]=0x1;
  array[14]=0x9;
  array[15]=0x3;

// calculate max 
max=array[0];

for(int i=1;i<16;i++)
{
    if(max<array[i])
    {
        max=array[i];
    }

}
printf("The max is %lx ",max);

 getch();
 return 0;
```

I want to find the position of the maximum value in the array and the position of the most significant binary 1 in the maximum value. As can be seen, the maximum value is 0x15 at position 13 in the array and the position of most significant binary 1 in the entry is 5th . How can this be accomplished in C?

Comment: If you want to find the position of your max value, keep it as an integer with your max variable.

Comment: @ Neil N. No it is not part of home work. Rather it is part of a project on which I am working.

Comment: Do you write this code?

Comment: @chux. Yes but with outside help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding index of max value in an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344192/finding-index-of-max-value-in-an-array-in-c)

Comment: @Winter. The array is added just as an example. In actual, the array will be calculated by preceding functions.

Comment: @Habib.Khan so your question is actually _How can I get the position of most significant binary 1 in a given value_. Correct.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this after the printf statement. and define j at the top.

```
for (j=0; j<16; j++) {
    if ((max=max>>1) == 0)  break;
}

printf("the max bit is %lx ", j);
```

this shows the bit position in conventional notation where the 5th bit is bit 4. add a '+1' to display as bit 5.

to display the position where the max occurs:

below the 'max=array[i]' line, add the following line (after defining maxpos with the other variables)

```
maxpos = i;
```

and change the printf to

```
printf("The max is 0x%02x at position 0x%02x ", max, maxpos);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I find the position of the maximum value in the array.

Comment: @Habib.Khan your program already __does__ find the maximum value in the array.

Comment: @Michael. the program finds the maximum but i was interested about the index of the maximum as well.

Comment: @Habib.Khan well then the title of your question is quite misleading.